# How to create and run a jar file with manifest file to support MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, gradle

I'm trying to build and run a Java application that relies on 'mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar'. I currently to this with the following commands using Terminal on MacOS, which works fine, however it doesn't work on Windows, so I'm trying an alternative approach using Docker, which results in an MySQL driver error message when running the app.

Steps to manually build and run using Terminal.

step 1: `find . -name "*.java" | xargs javac -d ./target`

step 2: `jar cfme my_app.jar manifest.txt Main -C ./target/ .`

step 3: `java -jar my_app.jar`

The manifest file includes a reference to the MySQL jar-file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar
```

As mentioned before, this solution works fine on Mac, but doesn't work on Windows.

So now I'm trying to use Docker to build and run the app instead. It was done this way before when the app didn't use MySQL and there was no need for the manifest file. I included steps to copy the manifest file in the Dockerfile as below, however when running the application I get an error: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3316/myDatabase`. I didn't get this error when I built the app manually using the 3 steps I listed out above.

Contents of Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-slim AS builder
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY lib /usr/src/app/lib
COPY manifest.txt /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN find . -name "*.java" | xargs javac -d ./target
RUN jar cfme my_app.jar manifest.txt Main -C ./target/ .
```

Steps to build and run the app using Docker:

1: `docker build -t projects/my_app -f Dockerfile ./`

2: `docker run -ti projects/my_app sh`

3: `java -jar my_app.jar`

How would I resolve the error or what would be a better approach to make this app more portable and easy to run on a different machine?

UPDATE 11/23:

I'm able to create a jar-file using Gradle, however when I run the application I get an error: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3316/myDatabase`

This is the contents of of my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'myApp.Main'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'
}
```

I'm new to Gradle, and appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: I recommend using a buid tool like [gradle (`gradle.org`)](https://gradle.org/) or [maven (`apache.maven.org`)](https://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: I'm new to Gradle, but I was able to to build an run a jar file using the steps found on [https://tomgregory.com/gradle-tutorial-for-complete-beginners/](https://tomgregory.com/gradle-tutorial-for-complete-beginners/), but was unable to find good instructions on how to include the mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar dependency to the build.gradle file. Any suggestions on how to to do that would be much appreciated.